# best way for python to interface with MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, json, http, get

I'm still very new to programming and trying to teach myself the correct ways of doing things.

I'm currently writing a script that will take 1-3 values, generated about every second, within python and then save it to a MySQL database. Down the road will build a web interface that will take those values and nicely display them, but for now I just want to save the data.

I will be running the Python code on a Raspberry Pi, and hopefully the web server with the MySQL server. If not on that device on another Raspberry Pi.

What I'm here asking is, what is the best way for Python to work with MySQL? Library or HTTP GET, or another way I don't know about... Since, I was going to build a web interface, I was thinking about having an API.php page that will take GET request and then the PHP code will write the data to the MySQL database.

What I had in mind was to have Python generate a link then use the request library to request the site e.g http://127.0.0.1/API.php?value1=XXX&Value2=YYY&value3=ZZZ  then wait for a JSON return of something like "Data Saved" if the data was saved correctly. Then continue the loop of generating the next value.

What that be the best way of going about this or is there a better way? I know that I will have some security issues, and I hope to resolve them once I learn more about coding. And remember that I want the data written every 1 or 5 seconds. Hopefully, every 1 second.

Thank you guys for your responses,
Throdne

Comment: You're looking for a Python *binding* to MySQL.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are a lot of ways you *could* do this, but since you stated that the MySQL server could be on the same Raspberry Pi *or* a different one, the following is the simplest way to get what you need set up.

First, you need to install a Python package which contains MySQL bindings. There are ton out there, but [`MySQL-python`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/MySQL-python/1.2.5) seems to be mature and good enough.

To install it:

```
$ pip install mysql
```

(If you're not already familiar with `pip`, check out the [`pip` documentation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/quickstart/) to get started.)

Once you've got a MySQL server running on one of your Raspberry Pis, here's an example what you'll need to do in the code to connect to the server and run various types of queries:

```
import MySQLdb

host = '192.168.99.100'
user = 'myuser'
password = 'secret'
port = 3306
db = 'test'

conn = MySQLdb.Connection(
    host=host,
    user=user,
    passwd=password,
    port=port,
    db=db
)

# Example of how to insert new values:
conn.query("""INSERT INTO mytable VALUES ('foo3', 'bar2')""")
conn.commit()

# Example of how to fetch table data:
conn.query("""SELECT * FROM mytable""")
result = conn.store_result()
for i in range(result.num_rows()):
    print(result.fetch_row())
```

Check the [MySQL-python user docs](http://mysqldb.readthedocs.org/en/latest/user_guide.html) for more details on how to use the library.

The above code assumes a couple of things about your MySQL server:

- Your server is running at `192.168.99.100`. It could be `127.0.0.1` (localhost) or another address.
- Your server already has the user `myuser` defined, with a password and appropriate permissions.
- You have already created a database called `test`.
- You have already created a table called `mytable` on database `test` which contains the VARCHAR fields of `foo` and `bar`.

I won't go into those details, since that's slightly out of scope for this thread, but if you need help have a look at the MySQL documentation for [creating users](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-user.html) and [creating tables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/creating-tables.html).

Comment: `sudo pip install mysql` fails on MacOS Sierra with `EnvironmentError: mysql_config not found`.

Comment: @EricFossum What's the issue?

Comment: ```
➜  ~ python3 -m pip install mysql
Collecting mysql
  ...
Collecting MySQL-python (from mysql)
  ...
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-r33d2gw7/MySQL-python/setup.py", line 13, in <module>
        from setup_posix import get_config
      File "/tmp/pip-build-r33d2gw7/MySQL-python/setup_posix.py", line 2, in <module>
        from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
```
I removed some fluff

Comment: @EricFossum It looks like a bug in the library. I just submitted a patch: https://github.com/farcepest/MySQLdb1/pull/136.

Comment: This should probably *not* be the top answer in 2022 as this package hasn't been updated in 8 years.. https://github.com/farcepest/MySQLdb1

Answer (score 4):

First install mysqlclient as this will also provide you support to work with Python 3.6

```
pip install mysqlclient
```

Example code

```
    import mysql.connector
    import _mysql
    db=_mysql.connect("127.0.0.1","root","umer","sys")
    #db=_mysql.connect(host,user,password,db)
    # Example of how to insert new values:
    db.query("""INSERT INTO table1 VALUES ('01', 'myname')""")
    db.store_result()
    db.query("SELECT * FROM new1.table1 ;") 
    #new1 is scheme table1 is table mysql 
    res= db.store_result()
    for i in range(res.num_rows()):
        print(result.fetch_row())
```

Comment: Doesn't work - `sh: mysql_config: command not found` when running `pip install mysql`

Answer (score 3):

`pip install mysql` failed for me on MacOS Sierra with `EnvironmentError: mysql_config not found`.

`pip install pymysql` works. [PyMySQL](https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL) is written in pure Python, so should be more cross-platform than statically compiled modules.

Example code:

```
import pymysql.cursors

# Connect to the database
connection = pymysql.connect(host='localhost',
                             user='user',
                             password='passwd',
                             db='db',
                             charset='utf8mb4',
                             cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)

try:
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        # Create a new record
        sql = "INSERT INTO `users` (`email`, `password`) VALUES (%s, %s)"
        cursor.execute(sql, ('webmaster@python.org', 'very-secret'))

    # connection is not autocommit by default. So you must commit to save
    # your changes.
    connection.commit()

    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        # Read a single record
        sql = "SELECT `id`, `password` FROM `users` WHERE `email`=%s"
        cursor.execute(sql, ('webmaster@python.org',))
        result = cursor.fetchone()
        print(result)
finally:
    connection.close()
```

Comment: I'm also on Sierra but can't presently use either: If anyone can help, this is my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46145845/cannot-make-remote-connection-with-pymysql-pymysql-err-internalerror-packet-se

Comment: wouldn't go with pymysql for serious projects ... the maintainer doesn't solve any bugs, he just asks you to go to stack overflow, for bugs that are obviously in the library. i mean i understand that people are busy, taking a long time to solve bugs is ok. but saying that bugs are "RARE" is not.

Answer (score 3):

**Python connect xampp mysql windows with pymysql:**

Step-1:

Run Command Prompt
    D:\python-3.6.2\Scripts> pip install pymysql

Step-2:

```
#!D:/python-3.6.2/python.exe 
print ("Content-Type: text/html\n")
import pymysql
conn = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', port=3306, user='root', passwd='', db='python_mysql')
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM authors")
print(cur.description)
print(" Test")
for row in cur:
    print(row)
cur.close()
conn.close()
```

Save the file as testconn.py in htdocs/PythonProject & open http://localhost/PythonProject\testconn.py

Crud Python & MySQL:

https://github.com/matinict/python-in-xampp-for-windows/

Answer (score 0):

```
import mysql.connector as connector


class DbHelper:
    def __init__(self):
        self.conn = connector.connect(host = '127.0.0.1', user = 'root', password = '', database = 'python_test')
##        print("Database connected...")

        query = 'create table if not exists user(userID int primary key, firstname varchar(200),lastname varchar(200), Dob varchar(15), contact varchar(10), address varchar(100))'
        curr = self.conn.cursor()
        curr.execute(query)
##        print("Table Created")
        print()


    def insert_Data(self, userID, firstname, lastname, Dob, contact, address):

        query = "insert into user (userID, firstname, lastname, Dob, contact, address) values({},'{}','{}','{}','{}','{}')".format(userID,firstname, lastname, Dob, contact, address)
            
        curr = self.conn.cursor()
        curr.execute(query)
        self.conn.commit()
        print(query)
        print("User data inserted....")

    def display_Data(self):
        query = 'select * from user'
##        print("query: ", query)
        print()

        curr = self.conn.cursor()
        curr.execute(query)

        for row in curr:
            print('userID :', row[0])
            print('firstname :', row[1])
            print('lastname :', row[2])
            print('Dob :', row[3])
            print('contact :', row[4])
            print('address :', row[5])
            print()
            print()
            
##        print(" All user data....")
        

    def delete_user(self, userID):

        query = "DELETE FROM user WHERE userID={}".format(userID)
        curr = self.conn.cursor()
        curr.execute(query)
        self.conn.commit()
##        print(query)
        print("Data delete for UserID " +str(userID))

    def update_Data(self, userID, newfirstname, newlastname, newDob, newcontact, newaddress):

        query = "update user set firstname = '{}', lastname ='{}', Dob = '{}', contact = '{}', address = '{}' where userID = {}".format(newfirstname, newlastname, newDob, newcontact, newaddress,userID)
        curr = self.conn.cursor()
        curr.execute(query)
        self.conn.commit()
##        print(query)
        print()
        print("Data updated for UserID " +str(userID))
           
        

##db = DbHelper()
##db.update_Data(1,'saurabh','sharma','25-06-1998','9892809732','malad')
```

Comment: Could you take the time to annotate this answer as python language? insert code in backtick fences